# Cannot assign, must be an instance -- Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Iam using Django and Rest Framework to POST data into an API, but while assigning a Form data of a foreign key using another table's primary key it throws an error
`"Cannot assign "'12345'": "ResourceSection.resourceId" must be a "MasterResource" instance."`

**Note:**  12345 does exist (created it for testing purpose)

Models.py

```
class MasterResource(models.Model):
    route_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    resourceId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
class ResourceSection(models.Model):
    resourceId = models.ForeignKey(MasterResource, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    resource_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    sectionId = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=100)
```

Views.py

```
def create_resource_section(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        sectionId = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
        resource_name = request.POST.get("resource_name")
        resourceId = request.POST.get("resourceId")
        try:
            section_object = ResourceSection(
                resourceId = resourceId,
                resource_name = resource_name,
                sectionId = sectionId
            )
            section_object.save()
            return HttpResponse(str(sectionId) + ' Section is successfully created')

        except Exception as e:
            return HttpResponseServerError(e)
```

Why the POST data couldnt set resourceId from MasterResource? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Because that's how Django's foreign key works.  You can't just supply a string.  You have to supply the object instance.  `rid = MasterResource.objects.filter(resourceId=request.POST.get("resourceId"))[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the error mentioned above I can see that you need to fetch the the MasterResource object and then pass the object in the Resource section.

```
def create_resource_section(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    sectionId = int(datetime.now(tz=timezone.utc).timestamp()*1000)
    resource_name = request.POST.get("resource_name")
    resourceId = request.POST.get("resourceId")
    resource_object = MasterResource.objects.get(resourceId=resourceId)

    try:
        section_object = ResourceSection(
            resourceId = resource_object,
            resource_name = resource_name,
            sectionId = sectionId
        )
        section_object.save()
        return HttpResponse(str(sectionId) + ' Section is successfully created')

    except Exception as e:
        return HttpResponseServerError(e)
```

Comment: Ahhh ok, it does make sense, understood the working. Thanks Madmax!!